# Accessing the array of Multidimensional array with indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I Want to access the id in this array. how can i access this array index  .

```
Array
(
    [Magnets] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [product] => Magnets
            [qty] => 2
            [price] => 250
        )

    [Lawn Suits , Summer Collection] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [product] => Lawn Suits , Summer Collection
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 1000
        )
```

Comment: Please specify if you want to access any particular id or all the ids.

Comment: i want to access all the records in arrray

Comment: Just use `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your array is named as `$results`. You can use `foreach` to loop through all values.

```
foreach( $results as $key => $result) {
    echo $result['id']; //This will give you id
    echo "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_column`

```
$aa = array_column($a, 'id');
```

DEMO : https://3v4l.org/biuRr